# Unrecognized configuration parameter when using set_config(text, text, boolean) in CTE

Tags: postgresql, cte, row-level-security

I'm trying to implement a simple ABAC system using row level security, with main policy defined as following:

```
CREATE policy resource_access ON resource
USING (
  (
    org_id::varchar = current_setting('scope.org.id', true)
  )
  AND 
  (
    acl_read && regexp_split_to_array(current_setting('scope.acl'), ',')::varchar[]
  )
)
```

Issuing queries akin to:

```
WITH 
  acl AS (SELECT set_config('scope.acl', 'ACL', true) "__acl"), 
  result AS ( ... )
SELECT * FROM acl, result
```

With the main reason to use **WITH** is to avoid multiple statements when queries are later **PREPARE**d and **EXECUTE**d by the Postgres driver I'm using.

The **result** in example above can contain any arbitrary queries required by the application. To ensure that **set_config** is executed in the query, it's also added to the final **SELECT**.

However, I still do consistently encounter the following error:

```
QueryFailedError: unrecognized configuration parameter "scope.acl"
```

Which appears to be caused by executing the subquery from `WITH` in isolation from the result query.

So the main questions are:

- Is there any elegant way to ensure running `set_config` before the main query (the one in `result`) is executed?
- Is there any better way to construct queries for the application side, to avoid using `WITH`, but keeping them as a single SQL statement?

Thank you!

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: We're on Postgres 12 at the moment

Answer (score 0):

We've ended up using the JOINs over CTEs, which implicitly applies the expected order, and queries looking like:

```
WITH
      acl AS (SELECT set_config('scope.acl', 'VALUE', TRUE) "__acl"),
      result AS (${query})
    SELECT * FROM bypass FULL OUTER JOIN result ON 1 = 1
```

In which case, `acl` CTE runs before the `result` and ensures that RLS could pick up a correct configuration.

Whilst it might very well be sub-optimal for a larger scale table, it worked perfectly for our scale (10k-100k rows) with no noticeable performance degradation compared to using CTEs without the resulting `FULL OUTER JOIN`. More importantly, our correctness tests haven't highlighted any deviations from the expected order, despite this behavior (of `result` running after `acl` in CTEs block) is implicit.